# Alphanumeric String Generation in C

Tags: c

Can anyone give me a complete example of how to generate an Alphanumeric String randomly 
like (ARG534UJ6) using C ? I'm completely new to C.

```
void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: No, we can't provide example! Because you first have to write some code and then we can help you to solve your problem. *Show your effort.* For [more..](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: `printf("ARG534UJ6");`

Comment: generate how - randomly?

Comment: yes for randomly generating

Comment: oid gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
}

Comment: Is there any compiler errors in the code? Also tell us what is len and what is the maximum length of the alphanumeric string you want

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working'? Does it give compiler errors, does it crash or give wrong results?

Comment: Just a caution, the real memory size of `char *s` should be `len + 1`. Also, I think your divisor for the mod operation should only be `sizeof(alphanum)` so the last character will be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by #IngoLeonhardt, use `% (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)` instead of `% sizeof(alphanum)`

My guess is that you don't have room for your string, try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = malloc(8 + 1);

    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand(time(NULL));  
    gen_random(str, 8);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only issue is `% (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)` instead of `% sizeof(alphanum)`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I think doing `% (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)` will exclude the last character in `alphanum`. Am I wrong? For example, for 10 characters you need to access indexes 0 to 9, a divisor of 9 will only give you indexes 0 to 8, ignoring the 9th character.

Comment: @n3rd4n1: `sizeof()` other than `strlen()` returns the array size of `alphanum`, including NUL.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt you are absolutely right!